# How do I group only the last `n` rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mariadb

Take the following table:

```
id - member_id - day

0      1         1
1      1         1
2      1         2
3      2         2
4      1         3
5      2         3
6      2         3
7      1         3
8      1         3
9      2         3
```

Lets say I want to do something like:

```
SELECT `day`,
    COUNT(`id`) AS `count`
FROM `table`
WHERE `member_id` = 1
GROUP BY `day`
ORDER BY `day` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

and I expected a result like:

```
day - count
3     3
2     1
1     1
```

Note how the count for day 1 is cut in half, as only the most recent five rows for that member are grouped. Instead, I get the last five groups, ordered by day.

How do I group only the most recent *n* rows with a WHERE condition?

Effectively, I want to use WHERE, then LIMIT, and only then GROUP.

Comment: You are selecting day from the query. That is all I know.

Comment: I do not totally understand, do you know about `HAVING` clause?

Comment: @LuisSiquot I don't see how `HAVING` gets me the most recent `n` rows for a given member..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use a subquery with `limit`:

```
SELECT `day`, COUNT(`id`) AS `count`
FROM (SELECT t.*
      FROM `table` t
      WHERE `member_id` = 1
      ORDER BY `day` DESC
      LIMIT 5
     ) t
GROUP BY `day`
ORDER BY `day` DESC;
```

Comment: I couldn't initially get a subquery to work, I realise now I may not have had the `WHERE` clause in it.